# Check for a substring in a String and move its order in the main string

Tags: bash, shell

```
main_string='{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}, {\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}'
substring='\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null'
```

Now I do the comparison to see if substring is present in main string like below:

```
if [[ $main_string=~ "$substring" ]]; then
```

But I'm not sure how to move it's order. I tried but I don't know how can I achieve moving or maintaining order while moving in bash.
(You can notice substring I selected, is the first string in main_string separated by ',' by other strings)

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you get rid of the backslashes? There's no need to escape double quotes inside single quotes; the backslashes become literal backslashes. Without them, seeing as this looks like JSON data, you'd be best served by using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) rather than raw string manipulation.

```
main_string='{"create":false,"name":"specified","queue":null,"rules":null},{"create":false,"name":"primaryGroup","queue":null,"rules":null},{"create":null,"name":"secondaryGroupExistingQueue","queue":null,"rules":null},{"create":null,"name":"default","queue":null,"rules":null}'
```

jq is tailor made for processing JSON data. It can query it, filter it, manipulate it, generate new JSON data, whatever you like. Here's what happens with the most basic query, `.`, which simply spits out the input data unchanged. Notice how jq parses it and pretty prints it. All I had to do was pass in `$main_string` wrapped in square brackets:

```
$ jq -r '.' <<< "[$main_string]"
[
  {
    "create": false,
    "name": "specified",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": false,
    "name": "primaryGroup",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": null,
    "name": "secondaryGroupExistingQueue",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": null,
    "name": "default",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  }
]
```

Here's how you could move an array element to the end:

```
$ jq '(.[] | select(.name=="specified")) as $elem | . - [$elem] + [$elem]' <<< "[$main_string]"
[
  {
    "create": false,
    "name": "primaryGroup",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": null,
    "name": "secondaryGroupExistingQueue",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": null,
    "name": "default",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  },
  {
    "create": false,
    "name": "specified",
    "queue": null,
    "rules": null
  }
]
```

Explanation:

- `.[]` loops over the four objects in the input array.
- `|` is a lot like shell pipes. It's how you chain together steps in jq, feeding the output of each "filter" to the next.
- `select(.name=="specified")` finds an object with the given `name` property.
- `as $elem` saves the object in a variable.
- `. - [$elem] + [$elem]` removes the object from the input array `.` and then adds it back at the end.

The end result is the object named `"specified"` is moved to the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but unfortunately I can't install jq. Need to do this using bash.

Comment: Also what if you want to move it to any other place and not always at end?

Comment: Read the jq manual. You'll have to play around with it. It's pretty much full fledged language.