# remove substring from a string with special characters using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Scenario 1:

```
string1=hello_how_are_you
string2=hello_ho
echo $string1 | sed -e "s/${string2}//g"
output : w_are_you
```

Scenario 2:

```
rule='\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null'
placement_rule='{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}'

echo $placement_rule |  sed -e "s/${rule}//g"

output : {\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}
```

As you can see in scenario2 no change in output, what can be done to replace /remove strings like these using sed.

Expected output should have been:

```
{},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Check for a substring in a String and move its order in the main string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131734/check-for-a-substring-in-a-string-and-move-its-order-in-the-main-string)

Comment: Would recommend a json way of dealing with such strings.

Comment: In scenario 1, I would use `${string1//$string2}` instead. In scenario 2, I would  treat JSON as the structured text it is and use the proper tools instead of treating it as a raw string.

Comment: And why are all the double quotes escaped?

Comment: @chepner thats how the input text i have

Answer (score 1):

Just use a tool like awk that understands literal strings (unlike sed which only understands regexps and backreference-enabled replacement text):

```
$ rule='\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null'

$ placement_rule='{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}'
```

.

```
$ echo "$placement_rule" | rule="$rule" awk 'BEGIN{rule=ENVIRON["rule"]; n=length(rule)} s=index($0,rule){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+n)} 1'
{},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}
```

or:

```
$ echo "$placement_rule" | awk 'BEGIN{rule=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; n=length(rule)} s=index($0,rule){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+n)} 1' "$rule"
{},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}
```

See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for info on why I'm using `ENVIRON or`ARGV[1]`to pass the shell variables value in rather than`-v`, i.e. backslashes are only literal the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
rule='\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null'
rule="$(echo "$rule" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\\\/g')"    # This line escapes the backslashes
placement_rule='{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"specified\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}'

echo $placement_rule |  sed -e "s/${rule}//g"
```

Output:

```
{},{\"create\":false,\"name\":\"primaryGroup\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"secondaryGroupExistingQueue\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null},{\"create\":null,\"name\":\"default\",\"queue\":null,\"rules\":null}
```

- The variable `$rule` needs to have escape sequences as `\\\"`
  which is then interpreted as `\"` in the `sed` replacement.
- The added conversion `s/\\/\\\\\\/g` replaces single backslash
  with three sequential backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

If the job is just to empty the first set of curly braces, it would be simpler not to use a complex `${rule}` variable, and just clear out those braces:

```
sed 's/{[^}]*}/{}/' <<< $placement_rule
```